# How do I add a column with a different number of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am calculating returns in R, and trying to add it to the current dataframe I am working with, but it doesnt work due to a difference in rows, where as existing rows are 194, and assigned data has 193 rows.

This code works just fine when doing it on its own:

```
diff(log(capm$price_Ford))
```

But when I try to assign it into the dataframe as its own column, I get the an error

```
capm$ford_ret <- diff(log(capm$price_Ford))
```

How can I assign the data with 193 rows, to a dataframe with 194 rows?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I assign the data with 193 rows, to a dataframe with 194 rows?

In a nutshell, you can’t. *Each column in a table must have the same number of rows.* You need to decide what to fill into the row that’s missing a value. Depending on your use-case, this might for example be `0` or `NA`. You also need to decide whether the missing value should go at the beginning or at the end (for a difference, usually at the beginning). For example:

```
capm$ford_ret <- c(NA, diff(log(capm$price_Ford)))
```